# Java Parametrized method explanation

Tags: java, generics, parametric-polymorphism

I would like to implement a Generic method inside a `CommonInterface` to implement it with different parameters and return Type.

Therefore I have:

```
public interface Common {
  public <T, N> T call(N n);
}
```

If I understand well Generics logic (maybe not..) the call method return a Type T and receive as parameter a Type N. Therefore:

```
public class Class implements Common {

  @Autowired private SomeService someService;
   
  @Override
  public <ClassDTO, Integer> ClassDTO call(Integer id) {
      String s = someService.doSome(id); // suppose doSome receive an Integer as param
  }
}
```

DoSome method is a simple method that receive as input parameter an Integer:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

 // some @Autowired other service

   public String doSome(Integer id) {
     // some operation

   }
}
```

I receive an error on doSome(id) call who said me:

```
The method doSome(java.lang.Integer) in the type SomeService is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)
```

It's like if:

```
public <ClassDTO, Integer> ClassDTO call(Integer id) {
}
```

The `Integer` above is not recognized as `java.lang.Integer`. I try to put `java.lang.Integer` as follows:

```
public <ClassDTO, java.lang.Integer> ClassDTO call(Integer id) {
}
```

but obtains other errors..

What's wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closer to the override of `call`:

```
public <ClassDTO, Integer> ClassDTO call(Integer id) {
  String s = someService.doSome(id); // suppose doSome receive an Integer as param
}
```

you could see that `ClassDTO` and `Integer` are **not** real types, but type parameters (like `T` and `N`), which are called that way. Not following the convention of naming type parameters can lead do the confusion you have.

The override is more clear when it's just like:

```
@Override
public <T, N> T call(N n) {
  ...
}
```

The types which replace the type parameters `ClassDTO` and `Integer` will be the ones, with which you call the `call()` method:

```
Class instance = new Class();
Integer integer = 5;
ClassDTO result = instance.<ClassDTO, Integer>call(integer);
```

This, however, will not resolve the compile-error when calling `service.doSome(id)`.

In order to make it compliling you can parametrize the `Common` interface with `T` and `N` and then your `Class` can implement the generic interface with specific types (`CommonDTO` and `Integer`):

```
public interface Common<T, N> {
  T call(N n);
}
```

The `Class` will then look like:

```
public class Class implements Common<CommonDTO, Integer> {

  private Service service;

  @Override
  public CommonDTO call(Integer n) {
    return service.doSome(n);
  }
}
```

which now compiles just fine.

Comment: Thanks this is the best answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply missing the fact that `Integer` in the body of your `call` method override is not the same as `java.lang.Integer`.

This happens often with generics when the simple single-uppercase-letter type variable naming convention is skipped.

The parameter `Integer id` is not of the same type as the one taken by `doSome`, presumably `java.lang.Integer`.

---

Side note: you're hiding implicitly imported classes (`Class`, `Integer`), which is known to lead to bugs; and that's beside not following the naming convention for type variables. Conventions sometimes help prevent bugs!